# How to get media type from a request when downloading?

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

Making a media downloader where I use

```
name = 0
for content in media_url_list:
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(content, str(name))
    name += 1
```

Problem with this is that the media type doesn't have a dedicated format when saved & if i put the name as

```
   str(name)+'.jpg'
```

then it doesn't work for gif files or other types.
Is there any way I can use urrlib to RECOGNIZE what type of file it is, so that I can assign the type to a variable & use it for naming it so that the type changes according to file type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png') as response:
   print(response.headers['Content-Type'])
```

That should print out "img/png".